# C - result of recvfrom unexpected

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ping, icmp

I have a simple code to send and receive ICMP packets like ping, everything works : my packet is sent and I received a result.
I have a problem in the recvfrom result, the ip dest/src in my buffer, isn't the server dest ip.

### Result

```
$> ./my_ping qwant.com
IPv4: hdr-size=20 pkt-size=56 protocol=1 TTL=254 src=10.0.2.2 dest=172.17.0.2
```

But with the real ping:

```
$> ping qwant.com
PING qwant.com (194.187.168.99): 48 data bytes
56 bytes from 194.187.168.99: icmp_seq=0 ttl=61 time=101.742 ms
```

It's not the same TTL and ip

## Code

#### Init struct addrinfo :

```
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *a_info;

bzero(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
hints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;

getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, &a_info)
```

#### Init socket :

```
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, (void *)&val, sizeof(val);
```

#### Send & Receive while :

```
size_t                  i;
t_ping                  pack;
int                     count = 1;
struct iphdr            buff;

while (TRUE)
{
    bzero(&pack, sizeof(pack));
    pack.head.type = 8;
    pack.head.code = getpid();
    pack.id = count++;

    while (i < 15)
    {
        pack.seq[i] = i + '0';
        i++;
    }
    pack.seq[i] = 0;
    pack.head.chk = checksum(&pack, sizeof(pack));
    ft_bzero((void *)&buff, sizeof(buff));

    if (sendto(sock, &pack, sizeof(pack), 0, a_info->ai_addr, a_info->ai_addrlen) < 0)
        perror("sendto");
    if (recvfrom(sock, (void *)&buff, sizeof(buff), 0, a_info->ai_addr, &a_info->ai_addrlen) < 0)
        perror("recvfrom");

    display((void *)&buff);
    sleep(1);
}
```

#### And finally my display func :

```
struct iphdr    *ip = buff;
char src[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
char dest[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

inet_ntop( AF_INET, (void *)&ip->saddr, src, sizeof(src) );
inet_ntop( AF_INET, (void *)&ip->daddr, dest, sizeof(dest) );


printf("IPv%d: hdr-size=%d pkt-size=%d protocol=%d TTL=%d src=%s dest=%s\n",
    ip->version,
    ip->ihl*4,
    ntohs(ip->tot_len),
    ip->protocol,
    ip->ttl,
    src,
    dest);
```

In my opinion, my buffer contains information about the last packet step (router -> my home) that explains why TTL value is 254 and why I found the same couple of IP with traceroute:

> $> traceroute qwant.com
>   traceroute to qwant.com (194.187.168.99), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
>     172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1)  0.026 ms  0.011 ms  0.010 ms
>     10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2)  0.149 ms  0.160 ms  0.156 ms
>    [...]
>     194.187.168.99 (194.187.168.99)  147.634 ms  147.506 ms  147.540 ms

Why is the information received not about my server target? How can I receive this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution :

I change my `getaddrinfo` call and my socket init :

```
getaddrinfo(stats.host, NULL, NULL, &addrinfo);
sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
setsockopt(sd, SOL_IP, IP_TTL, &val, sizeof(val));
```

Next I have create 2 `struct sockaddr_in` : one for `sendto` and the 2nd for `recvfrom`.

```
struct sockaddr_in send;
struct sockaddr_in recv;
```

Now init the send struct for specify the destination at `sendto`, but no change recv : It was automaticly assigned during the first `recvfrom` call.

```
bzero(&send, sizeof(send));
send.sin_family = addrinfo->ai_family;
send.sin_port = 0;
send.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)addrinfo->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
```

Finaly I have change my packet struct

```
struct packet
{
    struct icmphdr hdr;
    char msg[PACKETSIZE-sizeof(struct icmphdr)];
};
```

Now, just call `sendto` and `recvfrom` like that:

```
socklen_t len = sizeof(recv);
sendto(sd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&send, sizeof(send));
recvfrom(sd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&recv, &len);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
>   following three blocks of the IP address space for private networks:
>
> ```
>           10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255
>           172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255
>           192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255
> ```

172.17.0.2 is an address in of a private network. I guess your machine is inside this network, and also the server.

`getaddrinfo()` can return you more than one address. Try to run over all the responses and check if you get also the Internet address.

from [man getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo):

> /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
>          Try each address until we successfully bind(2).
>          If socket(2) (or bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
>          and) try the next address. */
>
> ```
> for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
>     sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
>             rp->ai_protocol);
>     if (sfd == -1)
>         continue;
>
>    if (bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
>         break;                  /* Success */
>
>    close(sfd);
> }
> ```

Comment: I just try it, but bind never worked for me... I have probably an other problem

Comment: @Dany Sousa: You can check if you have more than 1 address without binding. Just use that same loop

Comment: Using this loop with just a printf and inet_ntop for convert dest adress to char * I have one only result : the server ip.
So rp->ai_next == null i have an only address ...

Comment: Ok, I have set the getaddrinfo parameter 'hints'  (3rd param) to null and I have 3 addresses in my struct addrinfo, all worked with function socket, but no one with bind.